# Why does this custom client side unobtrusive MVC validation not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to put together a simple form using ASP.NET MVC and I am having trouble trying to make custom client side client side unobtrusive validation to work. It the last two days I have sipped through dozens of tutorials, blogs, and other pages regarding ASP.NET client validation. The information out there is confusing, incomplete and contradictory. The best I could find is some marketing mumbo jumbo how cool it is and then some code, with no explanation of used functions.

I will post my html code here because I am almost 100% certain that the problem is on the client side. Here is a simplified html that my view creates, for you convenience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function myValidationFunction(value) {
            return false;
        }


        jQuery.validator.addMethod("mycustomvalidation", function (value, element, params) {
            return myValidationFunction(value);
        });

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("mycustomvalidation", ["other", "comp", "value"],
            function (options) {
                options.rules['requiredif'] = {
                    other: options.params.other,
                    comp: options.params.comp,
                    value: options.params.value
                };
                options.messages['mycustomvalidation'] = options.message;
            }
        );


    </script>

    <form action="/test.htm" method="post">

        <label for="Field1">Field1</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Field1 is required." id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid error-text" data-valmsg-for="Field1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        <label for="Field2">Field2</label>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-myvalidation="Field2 is not valid" data-val-myvalidation-validationcallback="myValidationFunction" id="Field2" name="Field2" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid error-text" data-valmsg-for="Field2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        <input type="submit" value="TEST" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For clarification, the Field1 uses built-in "Required" validation. I have included it just to check that jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js actually work.

I will describe my reasoning so far. In some blog I have found that all you need to do is create meta tag data-val-myvalidation-validationcallback="myValidationFunction" which will wire validation to function myValidationFunction. All is left to do is implement this function in script. Of course, this does not work.

Another tutorial was saying something about parsing form after document is loaded, parsing metatags and making aproproate connection. Well, this is not true also.

Comment: Are you initializing the validate plugin like:`$('#YourFormID').validate({});` ?

Comment: @Jaggan_j No. This is the first time that I see something like that. Nowhere was it mentioned. As i said, all the tutorials are contraticting and none of them is working.